# How do i see which ssh key i’m using when pulling with git pull?

Tags: git, ssh

How do I see which ssh key i’m using when pulling with git pull?

I can see how to specify a key with `~/.ssh/config` (https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use ) but it would be great to get some output that says exactly which key I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify verbosity level to `ssh` by passing it in the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git pull
```

That will probably give you more info that you want.

Filter to taste:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git pull 2>&1 | awk -F\: '/Offering.*key/ { print $3 }'
```